# How to design an html table with multiple rows against a row using <div> tag

Tags: html, tabular

I know how to build table layout with div tags.

What I am looking for is an efficient way to build table with multiple rows against a single row using `<div>` tags as opposed to `<table>` tags as a large amount of data is going to be displayed.

Here is what I am looking to achieve:

[image]

Comment: If you need a table, why not use a `<table>`?

Comment: If the data you have is tabular, then you should use a table. If the data you have is not tabular, you should still use a table as getting what you want to work with divs alone would be a nightmare that I'm not even sure is fully achievable.

Comment: Are you building a table or a grid of non-tabular data? Your use of "html table" and "div tags" in the same sentence makes it very unclear.

Comment: Can the height of the rows be fixed?

Comment: And beyond the `<div>`/`<table>` confusion, what do you mean by “efficient”? What code have you got so far?

Comment: @GrahamClark - I am told that `<div>`'s are better than `<tr><td>`'s when we are displaying a large amount of data - and that is the case here.

Comment: @ring bearer I've never heard that argument.

Comment: @ringbearer I don't think that is correct at all. If you are displaying tabular data, use a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need divs.  Just use the rowspan property:  Here is a pretty styled table to get you started:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#customers
{
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
width:100%;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
#customers td, #customers th 
{
font-size:1em;
border:1px solid #98bf21;
padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
}
#customers th 
{
font-size:1.1em;
text-align:left;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:4px;
background-color:#A7C942;
color:#ffffff;
}
#customers tr.alt td 
{
color:#000000;
background-color:#EAF2D3;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table id="customers">
<tr>
  <th>Company</th>
  <th>Contact</th>
  <th>Country</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
<td>Maria Anders</td>
<td>Germany</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
<td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
<td>Christina Berglund</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
<td>Francisco Chang</td>
<td>Mexico</td>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The rowspan="2" is the key for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to agree with everyone else and say that tables are almost always better for tabular data. Specifically, I've never heard the argument (nor does it make much sense) that divs are preferable for a large amount of data.

However, if you need to accomplish something like this with pure divs, it's fairly simple as long as the rows have fixed heights. Simply organize the "table" into column divs. Then assign each inner cell a height, either the height of a row or half the height.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wn56N/1/

Comment: +1 - for answering to the question - wish i could upvote more. Great example. Accepting @Paxwell's answer from a "correctness" standpoint.